# Drawing an ellipse at an angle between two points in Javascript

Tags: javascript, geometry, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I'm trying to draw an ellipse between two points. So far, I have it mostly working by adding the angle of the line to the theta of the circle function, but the issue comes with setting the ellipse height (ellipse_h below, controlled by the height slider).

Can anyone please help me rotate the ellipse height? Thank you!

```js
const height_slider = document.getElementById("height_slider");
const height_readout = document.getElementById("height_readout");
const x1_slider = document.getElementById("x1_slider");
const x1_readout = document.getElementById("x1_readout");
const y1_slider = document.getElementById("y1_slider");
const y1_readout = document.getElementById("y1_readout");
const x2_slider = document.getElementById("x2_slider");
const x2_readout = document.getElementById("x2_readout");
const y2_slider = document.getElementById("y2_slider");
const y2_readout = document.getElementById("y2_readout");
const reset = document.getElementById("reset");
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function distance(x1, y1, x2,  y2)
{
    // Calculating distance
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) * 1.0);
}

function midpoint(x1, y1, x2,  y2)
{
  return [(x1 + x2) / 2,(y1 + y2) / 2];
}

function angle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
  //radians
  return Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
}


//https://www.mathopenref.com/coordcirclealgorithm.html
function draw_circle()
{
  let x1 = parseFloat(x1_slider.value);
  let y1 = parseFloat(y1_slider.value);
  let x2 = parseFloat(x2_slider.value);
  let y2 = parseFloat(y2_slider.value);
  var p1 = [x1,y1];
  var p2 = [x2,y2];
  var mid = midpoint(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]);
  var step = 2*Math.PI/20;
  var cx = mid[0];
  var cy = mid[1];
  var r = distance(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]) * 0.5;
  var ellipse_h = parseFloat(height_slider.value);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
  ctx.beginPath();

  var deg = angle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  var cos = Math.cos(deg * Math.PI /180);
  var sin = Math.sin(deg * Math.PI /180);
  for(var theta=0; theta <= Math.PI; theta+=step)
  {
    var x = cx + r*Math.cos(theta-deg);
    var y = cy - ellipse_h * r*Math.sin(theta-deg);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#22FF00";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(p1[0], p1[1], 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(p2[0], p2[1], 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();

  x1_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(x1_slider.value*100)/100;
  x2_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(x2_slider.value*100)/100;
  y1_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(y1_slider.value*100)/100;
  y2_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(y2_slider.value*100)/100;
  height_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(ellipse_h*100)/100;
}

const default_x1 = 100;
const default_y1 = 150;
const default_x2 = 200;
const default_y2 = 150;
const default_height = 1;

function reset_defaults()
{
  x1_slider.value = default_x1;
  y1_slider.value = default_y1;
  x2_slider.value = default_x2; 
  y2_slider.value = default_y2;
  height_slider.value = default_height;

  draw_circle();  
}

x1_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
x2_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
y1_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
y2_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
height_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
reset.onclick = reset_defaults;


reset_defaults();
```

```css
#canvas
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #272727;
}

#controls
{
  font-family: Arial, sans;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.control
{
  display: inline-block;
}

h4
{
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0;
}

.control input
{
  width: 40px;
}

#height,#reset
{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="controls">
<h4>Point 1</h4>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="100" id="x1_slider">X1:<text id="x1_readout" style="inline">100</text>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="100" id="y1_slider">Y1:<text id="y1_readout" style="inline">100</text>
</div>
<h4>Point 2</h4>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="200" id="x2_slider">X2:<text id="x2_readout" style="inline">200</text>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="100" id="y2_slider">Y2:<text id="y2_readout" style="inline">100</text>
</div>
<div class="control" id="height">
  <input type="range" min="-6.28318530718" max="6.28318530718" step="0.001" value="1" id="height_slider">Height:<text id="height_readout" style="inline">1</text>
</div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas provides a [method to draw ellipse arcs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse), all you have to do identify the parameters on your ellipse.

Let the center be the midpoint between the two points, `radiusX` be the half the distance between the two points, and rotation the angle of the line connecting them. All you have to do is to set `radiusY`.

```js
const height_slider = document.getElementById("height_slider");
const height_readout = document.getElementById("height_readout");
const x1_slider = document.getElementById("x1_slider");
const x1_readout = document.getElementById("x1_readout");
const y1_slider = document.getElementById("y1_slider");
const y1_readout = document.getElementById("y1_readout");
const x2_slider = document.getElementById("x2_slider");
const x2_readout = document.getElementById("x2_readout");
const y2_slider = document.getElementById("y2_slider");
const y2_readout = document.getElementById("y2_readout");
const reset = document.getElementById("reset");
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function distance(x1, y1, x2,  y2)
{
    // Calculating distance
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) * 1.0);
}

function midpoint(x1, y1, x2,  y2)
{
  return [(x1 + x2) / 2,(y1 + y2) / 2];
}

function angle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
  //radians
  return Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
}


//https://www.mathopenref.com/coordcirclealgorithm.html
function draw_circle()
{
  let x1 = parseFloat(x1_slider.value);
  let y1 = parseFloat(y1_slider.value);
  let x2 = parseFloat(x2_slider.value);
  let y2 = parseFloat(y2_slider.value);
  var p1 = [x1,y1];
  var p2 = [x2,y2];
  var mid = midpoint(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]);
  var step = 2*Math.PI/20;
  var cx = mid[0];
  var cy = mid[1];
  var r = distance(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]) * 0.5;
  var ellipse_h = parseFloat(height_slider.value);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
  ctx.beginPath();

  /*var deg = angle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  var cos = Math.cos(deg * Math.PI /180);
  var sin = Math.sin(deg * Math.PI /180);
  for(var theta=0; theta <= Math.PI; theta+=step)
  {
    var x = cx + r*Math.cos(theta-deg);
    var y = cy - ellipse_h * r*Math.sin(theta-deg);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
  }*/
  
  ctx.ellipse(
    // center
    (x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2,
    // radiusX
    Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1) / 2,
    // radiusY
    Math.abs(ellipse_h),
    // rotation
    Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1),
    // start angle
    ellipse_h >= 0 ? 0: -Math.PI,
    // end angle
    ellipse_h >= 0 ? Math.PI : 0
  );
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#22FF00";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(p1[0], p1[1], 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(p2[0], p2[1], 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();

  x1_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(x1_slider.value*100)/100;
  x2_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(x2_slider.value*100)/100;
  y1_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(y1_slider.value*100)/100;
  y2_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(y2_slider.value*100)/100;
  height_readout.innerText = Math.ceil(ellipse_h*100)/100;
}

const default_x1 = 100;
const default_y1 = 150;
const default_x2 = 200;
const default_y2 = 150;
const default_height = 10;

function reset_defaults()
{
  x1_slider.value = default_x1;
  y1_slider.value = default_y1;
  x2_slider.value = default_x2; 
  y2_slider.value = default_y2;
  height_slider.value = default_height;

  draw_circle();  
}

x1_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
x2_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
y1_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
y2_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
height_slider.oninput = draw_circle;
reset.onclick = reset_defaults;


reset_defaults();
```

```css
#canvas
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #272727;
}

#controls
{
  font-family: Arial, sans;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.control
{
  display: inline-block;
}

h4
{
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0;
}

.control input
{
  width: 40px;
}

#height,#reset
{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="controls">
<h4>Point 1</h4>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="100" id="x1_slider">X1:<text id="x1_readout" style="inline">100</text>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="100" id="y1_slider">Y1:<text id="y1_readout" style="inline">100</text>
</div>
<h4>Point 2</h4>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="200" id="x2_slider">X2:<text id="x2_readout" style="inline">200</text>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" min="0.001" max="300" step="0.001" value="100" id="y2_slider">Y2:<text id="y2_readout" style="inline">100</text>
</div>
<div class="control" id="height">
  <input type="range" min="-200" max="200" step="0.001" value="10" id="height_slider">Height:<text id="height_readout" style="inline">1</text>
</div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

In order to use negative `ellipse_h` we have change the start and end angles.